# How AsyncTask implement, in this code to refresh?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

The following code extract ANDROID MYSQL reading JSON data from a PHP How can I do to do it every 10 seconds and the ListView is refreshed, the app basically this always consulted the database constantly running PHP to reread the JSON code generated every 10 seconds, thanks in advance for any help or suggestions
Here's the code:

```
 public class VerA extends ActionBarActivity {

 String myJSON;
private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "nombre";
private static final String TAG_ADD ="telefono";
JSONArray peoples = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    getData();

}


 // METOD SHOW LIST
protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
            persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
            persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);

            personList.add(persons);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                VerA.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


   ///METOD GET DATA JSON READ FROM PHP 
public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://tuescuelanoticias.x10.mx/selectAllJSON.php");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}




}
```

UPDATE POST: ADD in onCreate this metod:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            getData();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    }, 0);

 }
```

Comment: you have to create a `Service` to call the `getData()` method every 10 mins

Comment: tankyou@helldawg13 i did this: in onCreate, add the next metod, and is working, but appeared a new problem, every time calling metod, the scroll, bar pull up, how can solved this.

Comment: i think so, run the metod getData every 10 secods, but only check a value in database who indicated exist a new data, and call again the get data.

Comment: it recreates the listview everytime you can the service